# How to debug issue where LaTeX refuses to produce more than 7 pages?

Tags: debugging

I consider myself quite experienced in this field by now. But today I am totally stumped. I have a .tex file where LaTeX truncates anything after page 7. It used to be that I had a `\newpage` in the middle of page 7 but if I remove that thing it will nicely place the things that should be on top of page 8 on the bottom of page 7 and then refuse to do page 8 so there is nothing at that specifik place ending the document. Rather it seems something else is going on. But how do I try to figure it out?

I have searched the log file for warnings and errors and all I have are a few warnings about fonts being loaded multiple times and some not being found so it uses fall backs. That can hardly be it I am thinking...

---

EDIT:

I have tried for a while now and decided to share my code: https://gist.github.com/jonalv/6305c13c491b65bf4d8e6cb709a41f18

in the hope that someone can figure it out...

Comment: Make a copy and then start to remove things until you find the culprit.

Comment: Do you get any warning and/or error messages? If so, what do they say?

Comment: tex only stops and finalizes the PDF if it executes `\@@end` which means in latex usually either `\end{document}` or `\stop`  so you are executing one of those somewhere around page 7...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Or there is an unbalanced brace that makes TeX to read everything up to the end and to give up; but in this case an error message would be issued.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle or an unbalanced `\iffalse` gobbling up the rest of the document.

Comment: @Skillmon if it is completely unbalanced the document wouldn't finalize and the pdf wouldn't be usable, so only I think if there is a matching `\fi` (or the user does something at the `*` prompt to finish up manually

Comment: `\let\clearpage\relax` is not a good idea ..., even more if you forget to close the group meant to keep this local.

Comment: Wow how did that get there? thanks!

Comment: It usually gets there as people want `\include` without forcing a page break, but it always breaks latex.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are getting a warning in the log:

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 70 ({)
### bottom level
```

This indicates something is wrong. And if one looks at line 70 one can see the culprit:

```
{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Databases exercise 1}
```

You are redefining `\clearpage` to do nothing but don't close the group as a brace is missing, and so `\clearpage` is missing at end document (where it is really needed).

Comment: I actually don't know why I would do this but good catch! and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not the most elegant solution, but I added a \newpage just before \end{document} and it compiles all the pages as intended.

Comment: This is not a solution. After _any_ error the PDF is not usable.